# How to mount multiple folders to same hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, raid

I have a microserver from hp and got a SSD, which I planned to use for the OS (Ubuntu Server 12.04), while two more harddisk should run in RAID 1. People recommended me that during installation of ubuntu server I should create a mount point pointing to my `/home` directory, so everything in my `/home` directory will automatically get backuped within the raid system.

I would like to use this raid to replace more folders, like for example I plan to install a SVN on the server. Usually those files are physically stored in `/var/local/svn` or something like that, but those svn files I would prefer to store on the raid system (/home). Should I just install everything I am planning to backup within folders on my /home - directory? That doesn't really sound like the Ubuntu way of handling this.

I also know, that I could create more partitions to mount more folders, but I am really not sure on how much space I should reserve for each of them, so I would prefer a more simple approach. What is the Ubuntu way of handling this? And can you maybe recommend me more folders of Ubuntu, I might should put on the raid? Are symbolic links the way to go here?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to access from where, but I guess you can use symbolic links for this. For instance, `ln -s /var/local/svn/dirname /home/user/dirname` will make the files that are physically stored in /var/local/svn/dirname accessible as if they were stored in /home/user/dirname. When the drive containing /var/local/svn is mounted, your files will be accessible, otherwise /home/user/dirname will appear empty. Is that what you would like to do?

Comment: sorry for late reply and thanks for your comment! actually I want to physically store the svn repositories (which are usually stored in /var/local/svn/dirname) on my raid system (which is NOT my os disk), Since /var/local/ would currently be on my os they wouldnt get backuped in raid. Nevertheless I havent really thought about symbolic links yet. Could I link every access to /var/local/ to an specific directory on my raid? Or should I really create the repositories on my home directory?

Comment: Once you have your hard disk correctly mounted, you can have as many symbolic links as you like. All of these would be just a name in /home that points to a directory in /var/local/svn.

Comment: But when I understand it correctly I would need this exaclty the other way round, meaning I have to create a symbolic link for /var/local/svn pointing to a directory in /home/svn or sth. to let every file which is planned to get stored in /var/local/svn actually gets stored in my /home/svn (raiddisc-) folder. Does that make any sense to you? would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, I assumed it to be the other way around. If /home/svn is on your RAID disk, create the links in /var/local/svn to point to subfolders of /home/svn. The syntax is `ln -s TARGET LINKNAME` so that would be `ln -s /home/svn/dir /var/local/svn/dir`.

Comment: thank you a lot for taking the time to help me. Feel free to post this as an answer. I read about symbolic links and this seems to solve my issue perfectly. I'll gladly accept it then!

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: @guntbert I think I had all the information already in the question, just a misunderstanding forced to some clearification in the comments, which I think was the purpose of those. Nevertheless I updated the question to add some more information to make the question clearer for the reader. Hope its satisfying for you.

Comment: From the sounds of it, the ssd in the server is rather pointless.  I'd say take it out and use it in your desktop or something instead and just let the whole server sit on the raid.

Comment: Yes, you might be right, but I dont have any need for another SSD in my desktop pc and I would rather prefer to use my RAID system only for storing data purposes. Is my approach to only store data that unusual? I expected it to be a more common usecase. Its just hard for me to differ between what folder in ubuntu might contain data and what else is just os depending stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use symbolic links.

```
ln -s /home/svn/dir /var/local/svn/dir
```

will make the files that are physically stored in /home/svn/dir accessible as if they were stored in /var/local/svn/dir. When the drive containing /home/svn is mounted, your files will be accessible, otherwise /var/local/svn/dir will appear empty.